# Flutter check for internet connection on app startup and show a snapbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a Flutter app for android/iOS and I would like to check if the device has an internet connection on the app startup and then show a SnackBar if it doesn't have one.

Is it a good idea to send an HTTP request and if it doesn't get a response in 5 seconds it will decide that the device doesn't have an internet connection? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The `connectivity` package does not guarantee the actual internet connection (could be just wifi connection without internet access).

This is what I got from documentation

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.

If you really need to check the connection to the www Internet the better choice would be

[internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

Comment: It says that the package doesn't support null safety so the app can't be built.

Comment: @DavidCZ2051 I have updated the answer internet connection checker plugin is created with data connection checker plugin's base code with null safety

Answer (score -1):

You can use [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package in your initState to check for internet connectivity

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
}
```